# pandas crashes on series with multiple data types

Tags: python, excel, pandas, group-by, crash

I have a simple excel file with two columns - one categorical column and another numerical column that i read into pandas with the read_excel function as below

```
df= pd.read_excel('pandas_crasher.xlsx')
```

The first column is of type Object with multiple types. Since the excel was badly formatted, the column contains a combination of timestamps, floats and texts. But its normally supposed to be just a simple textual column

```
from datetime import datetime
from collections import Counter

df['random_names'].dtype
```

> dtype('O')

**`print Counter([type(i) for i in load_instance['random_names']])`**

> Counter({type 'unicode'>: 15427, type 'datetime.datetime'>: 18,
>   type 'float'>: 2})

When i do a simple groupby on it, it **`crashes the python kernel`** without any error messages or notifications - i tried doing it from both jupyter and a small custom flask app without any luck.

**`df.groupby('random_names')['random_values'].sum()`** << crashes

Its a relatively small file of 700kb (15k rows and 2 cols) - so its definitely not a memory issue

I tried debugging with pdb to trace the point at which crashes but couldnt get past the the cython function in the pandas/core/[groupby.py module](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/v0.17.1/pandas/core/groupby.py)

> def _cython_operation(self, kind, values, how, axis)

a possible bug in pandas - instead of crashing directly shouldnt it throw an exception and quit gracefully ?

I then convert the various datatypes into text with the following function

```
def custom_converter(x):
    if isinstance(x,datetime)  or isinstance( x, ( int, long, float ) ):
        return str(x)
    else:
        return x.encode('utf-8')

df['new_random_names'] = df['random_names'].apply(custom_converter)

df['new_random_names'].groupby('random_names')['random_values'].sum() << does not crash
```

The apply custom function is probably the slowest way of doing this. Is there any better/faster way of doing this ?

Excel file here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ZLijGO6gbLelBXMjJWRFV3a2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It works just fine for me - Python 3.5.1 (64-bit), Pandas 0.18.0

Comment: It is possible that it is indeed a memory issue, since almost all the values in your `random_names` column are unique.  This means there are ~15k groups in your groupby.

Comment: @MaxU: Out of curioisity, what is your platform and numpy version?  It looks like the problem may be with numpy rather than pandas.

Comment: Just checked it with `Python 2.7.11` - it crashed as well

Comment: My platform: `Windows 7 64-bit`, `numpy 1.10.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the crash seems to happen when pandas tries to sort the group keys.  If I pass the `sort=False` argument to `.groupby()` then the operation succeeds.  This may work for you as well.  The sort appears to be a numpy operation that doesn't actually involve pandas objects, so it may ultimately be a numpy issue.  (For instance, `df.random_names.values.argsort()` also crashes for me.)

After some more playing around, I'm guessing the problem has to do with some sort of obscure condition that arises due to the particular comparisons that are made during numpy's sort operation.  For me, this crashes:

```
df.random_names.values[14005:15447]
```

but leaving one item off either end of the slice doesn't crash anymore.  Making a copy of this data and then tweaking it by taking out individual elements, the crash will occur or not depending on whether certain seemingly random elements are removed from the data.  Also, under certain circumstances it will fail with an exception of "TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to unicode" (or "datetime to float").

This section of the data contains one datetime and one float value, which happens to be a `nan`.  It looks like there is some weird edge case in the numpy code that causes failed comparisons to crash under certain circumstances rather than raise the right exception.

To answer the question at the end of your post, you may have an easier time using the various arguments to `read_excel` (such as the `converters` argument) to read all the data in as textual values right from the start.

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn. Sort=False did the trick. Not sure if its worth while filing a bug with numpy.